# Overflow/ Underflow in Smart Contract

Tags: smart-contracts, michelson

Is Tezos vulnerable to overflow/ underflow attacks on the smart contracts? If yes, how do you recommend to test whether a particular smart contract suffers from it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have two amounts (`mutez`): `t1` and `t2`; `t1 - t2` underflows when `t2` is bigger than `t1`.

There is a similar overflow on `mutez` (they are 64 bits values).

Shifts are also problematic (`LSL` and `LSR` in Michelson).

When such an event happens, an exception is raised and that cancels the whole transaction.

Testing is not easy. For these cases, I personally think that they are a very good  use case for automatic static analysis.

Comment: Why wouldn't testing be easy? If you set up a testing environment, you can call the contracts from a JavaScript environment and the calls to the contract should throw on overflows.

Comment: If `t1 - t2` becomes negative, it's still considered overflow. Underflow refers to floats becoming so small that they are rounded to 0.

Comment: You call it what you wish. It’s called underflow in the tezos documentation that you may wish to read.

Comment: In that case, that is an error in the documentation that should be fixed. It is a pretty bad idea for projects to start inventing their own definitions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was wondering more of Nat or Int in this case. Will it be the same as the problem mutez is facing?

Comment: They are fine except for shifts (LSL and LSR).